# Conversion from vector<string> to char** only carries the first element

Tags: c++, c++11

I have heavily commented the code below with my problem. Basically the problem is that I am trying to fake `argv` by a `std::vector<std::string>` but I am getting a behavior from Visual Studio that is not expected by me. Could you please elaborate on what I am missing here?

```
std::vector<std::string> argv_storage;
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    // I copy output of generate_rand_str() because I will need it
    // later in the code.
    argv_storage.push_back( std::string( generate_rand_str() ) );
}

std::vector<char *> argv( argv_storage.size() + 1 );    // one extra for NULL
for (std::size_t i = 0; i != argv_storage.size(); ++i)
{
    argv[i] = &argv_storage[i][0];
}

// Here if I access elements like argv.data()[index]
// they are perfectly fine but when I do:

char** test = argv.data();
// Visual Studio debugger only shows argv.data()[0]

// I want to pass this to glutInit() ...
int argc = argv.size() - 1; // one less for the NULL
glutInit(&argc, argv.data());

// Inspection of arguments passed to glutInit() also shows that ONLY the
// the first element of argv is passed.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**tl;dr** Your call to `glutInit` is wrong. See below.

---

Despite what many other contributors are claiming, your individual C-strings are perfectly well NULL-terminated because in C++11 (which you're using) it is guaranteed for `str.operator[](str.size())` to evaluate to the null character:

> `[C++11: 21.4.5]:`
>
> `const_reference operator[](size_type pos) const;`
>   `reference operator[](size_type pos);`
>
> **1** Requires: `pos <= size().`
>   **2** Returns: `*(begin() + pos)` if `pos < size()`, **otherwise a reference to an object of type `T` with value `charT()`**; the referenced value shall not be modified.

*(Strictly speaking this doesn't state that `*(&str.operator()(str.size()-1)+1)` is `charT()`, but that NULL **must** be stored in the actual data buffer in order for an implementation to abide by the constant-time access guarantee of the string.)*

So there is no need at all to resort to storing the result of `str.c_str()`, though that is a valid  alternative approach.

And, since vectors default-initialise their members, your `argv` itself is also null-terminated.

Therefore **there is no problem with your vector**; I cannot reproduce your problem when I abstract away OpenGL:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> argv_storage;
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        // I copy output of generate_rand_str() because I will need it
        // later in the code.
        argv_storage.push_back(std::to_string(i));
    }

    std::vector<char *> argv( argv_storage.size() + 1 );    // one extra for NULL
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i != argv_storage.size(); ++i)
    {
        argv[i] = &argv_storage[i][0];
    }

    char** test = argv.data();
    while (*test != NULL) {
        std::cout << *(test++) << ' ';
    }
}

// 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

([live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3643863d0443610e))

However, `glutInit` expects a *pointer* to the data buffer size, rather than the size itself. So, when you're passing `argv.size()`, that's wrong.

Try this:

```
int argv_size = argv.size();
glutInit(&argv_size, argv.data());
```

Comment: *"So there is no need at all to resort to storing the result of str.c_str() (which becomes unsafe as soon as you invoke a non-const member on str, anyway)."* It seems to me that taking the pointer `&str[0]` is no more safe, because invoking a non-const member might trigger a reallocation, and then the taken pointer becomes invalid. I would still prefer `data()` or `c_str()` (which do the same thing in C++11) over taking the pointer to the first element of the string since that's the documented way to obtain a C-style string from a string object and there are at least guarantees about when...

Comment: In the end of your first paragraph, do you mean the *null character*?

Comment: @cdhowie: That's fair.

Comment: @JasonR: Yes, I do. :)

Comment: ... the pointer will be invalidated. I'm not sure if there are strict guarantees about when the pointer `&str[0]` becomes invalid. (Though I suspect a sane implementation will return `&str[0]` from `data()` and `c_str()` but again this isn't guaranteed.) It's probably the same thing in the end, so... *shrug*

Comment: @cdhowie: I've changed it to just point out that switching to `c_str()` is pointless and at the very least doesn't "fix" anything here.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yup, makes sense. It would have been a fix in C++03 but, alas, I did not see the C++11 tag. :( +1

Answer (score 2):

`glutInit` takes a `int *` as it's first argument, not an `int`.

Your vector/string stuff looks messy but right.

Comment: I was actually passing an `int*` (dumbly not shown in code above) but your comment about `glutInit` makes perfect sense since glut modifies argv and argc therefore everything becomes chaos. Do you have a solution that is glut-proof?

Comment: @3p3r: Why don't you show us your _actual_ code? Then we can help you diagnose it. Rather than generating a new program for you.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I updated it, that's literally it. All my code is like that, the generate_rand_str() is irrelevant honestly since it comes from the Lua side and I can just have a random string generation algorithm there and it makes no difference to what I want to do. Plus I am copying the output of it anyway. It returns `char*`

Comment: @3p3r: Then I still don't really see what you're asking. We've proven that your code is fine. You ask us to tell you what you're missing but you're not missing anything and not showing any evidence to the contrary!